# One question about the improper integral

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals

compute the integral 
$$\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2}dx$$

Actually, I have used the new invariable $t=\sqrt{x}$, and then divide the integral into two parts. However, it seems that every single part does not exist. Wish you could give me some hints.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by *every single part does not exist*?!
Clearly $\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2}\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^+)$ and
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x}}{1+x^2}\,dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2x^2}{1+x^4}\,dx = \int_{0}^{1}\frac{2(x^2+1)}{x^4+1}\,dx $$
can be written as 
$$ 2\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1+x^2-x^4-x^6}{1-x^8}\,dx = 2\sum_{n\geq 0}\left(\frac{1}{8n+1}+\frac{1}{8n+3}-\frac{1}{8n+5}-\frac{1}{8n+7}\right) $$
where the reflection formula for the $\psi=\frac{\Gamma'}{\Gamma}$ function ensures that the RHS equals
$$ \frac{1}{4}\left[\pi\cot\frac{\pi}{8}+\pi\cot\frac{3\pi}{8}\right] = \color{red}{\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}}}.$$
You may easily achieve the same by applying the residue theorem.

Comment: Thank you for your help! By using the residue theorem, I have checked the result. Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 1):

As you might have seen in the other answers the substitutution $t=\sqrt[] {x}$ will do. So the integral becomes:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{2t^2} {1+t^4}\,dt=\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{t^2} {1+t^4}\,dt=\Re\left( \int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{1} {t^2-i}\,dt\right)
\end{align}
The one on the RHS can be easily done with the residue theorem. Just use a semi circle contour in the upper half plane and the residue inclosed is then $z=\alpha=e^{i\pi/4}$. Moreover the integral on the circle part has no contribution when the radius goes to infinity. And the residue is equal to : $$\text{Res}_{z=\alpha}\frac{1} {z^2-i} =\frac{1}{e^{i\pi/4}-e^{-i\pi/4}}=-\frac{e^{3\pi/4}}{2i}$$
Hence:
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty \frac{2t^2} {1+t^4}\,dt=\Re\left(2\pi i \text{Res}_{z=\alpha}\frac{1} {z^2-i} \right) = \pi \frac{\sqrt[] {2}} {2} 
\end{align}
So we can conclude:

> \begin{align} \int_0^\infty \frac{\sqrt[] {x}} {1+x^2}\,dx=\pi \frac{\sqrt[] {2}} {2}\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

If you use the substitution $x=y^2$ and $\mathrm dx=2y\,\mathrm dy$, your integral becomes$$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{2y^2}{1+y^4}\,\mathrm dy,$$which can be computed using partial fraction decomposition.

Comment: Actually, the integral of two parts which have been divided seems not to exist, I have checked that.

Comment: @Joshua This integral converges. What are the two parts that you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{2t^2-2}{t^4+1}+\frac{2}{t^4+1}$$
These fractions are easy to integrate if you divide first fraction by $t^2$ in both numerator and denominator and then try to complete $(t-\frac{1}{t})^2$  in denominator and then letting it other variable

And both integral does exist..

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively your integral can be evaluated by first converting it to a [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) of the following form
$$\text{B} (m,n) = \int^\infty_0 \frac{x^{m - 1}}{(1 + x)^{m + n}} \, dx.$$

If in the integral we let $x \mapsto \sqrt{x}$, then
\begin{align*}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1 + x^2} \, dx &= \frac{1}{2} \int^\infty_0 \frac{x^{-1/4}}{1 + x} \, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \int^\infty_0 \frac{x^{\frac{3}{4} - 1}}{(1 + x)^{\frac{3}{4} + \frac{1}{4}}} \, dx\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \text{B} \left (\frac{3}{4}, \frac{1}{4} \right ).
\end{align*}

Using the following well-known relation between the Beta and the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Relation_to_other_functions) of
$$\text{B} (x,y) = \frac{\Gamma (x) \Gamma (y)}{\Gamma (x + y)},$$
we can write
\begin{align*}
\int^\infty_0 \frac{\sqrt{x}}{1 + x^2} \, dx &= \frac{1}{2} \frac{\Gamma (\frac{3}{4}) \Gamma (\frac{1}{4})}{\Gamma (1)}\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \Gamma (1 - \frac{1}{4}) \Gamma (\frac{1}{4}), \quad {\rm since} \,\, \Gamma (1) = 1\\
&= \frac{1}{2} \frac{\pi}{\sin \left (\frac{\pi}{4} \right )}\\
&= \frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}},
\end{align*}
where in the second last line we have made use of [Euler's reflection formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Genera).